# Why are my tikz graphs not side-by-side?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, horizontal-alignment, includegraphics, subfig

With `\includegraphics` and PNG images I'm able to align graphics side by side. However, when I replace `\includegraphics` with a `tikzpicture`, the graphs are not side by side. Instead, they are one on top of the other. Is there a way to make tikz graphs side by side?

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.15\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',node distance=1cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]
  \node[main node] (1) [label=above:{$Z$}]{};
  \node[main node] (2) [below left =0.5cm of 1,label=left:$X$]{};
  \node[main node] (3) [below right =0.5cm of 1,label=right:$Y$] {};
  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node {} (2)
    (1) edge node {} (3)
    (2) edge node {} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.15\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',node distance=1cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]
  \node[main node] (1) [label=above:{$Z$}]{};
  \node[main node] (2) [below left =0.5cm of 1,label=left:$X$]{};
  \node[main node] (3) [below right =0.5cm of 1,label=right:$Y$] {};
  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node {} (3)
    (2) edge node {} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the empty line between the sub-figures?

Comment: omigosh @gernot! that was it, thank you! Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `subfigure` environment becomes a box (a `minipage`). The empty line between the boxes starts a new paragraph, so they will be typeset below each other.

To put the `subfigure`s side by side, replace the empty line by a horizontal space like `\quad`, `\qquad`, `\hspace{...}`, `\hfill`, or nothing at all.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\quad
\begin{figure}
  \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',node distance=1cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]
  \node[main node] (1) [label=above:{$Z$}]{};
  \node[main node] (2) [below left =0.5cm of 1,label=left:$X$]{};
  \node[main node] (3) [below right =0.5cm of 1,label=right:$Y$] {};
  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node {} (2)
    (1) edge node {} (3)
    (2) edge node {} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\quad
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',node distance=1cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]
  \node[main node] (1) [label=above:{$Z$}]{};
  \node[main node] (2) [below left =0.5cm of 1,label=left:$X$]{};
  \node[main node] (3) [below right =0.5cm of 1,label=right:$Y$] {};
  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node {} (3)
    (2) edge node {} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```